# We need better ways to explain to users how the site should work

Tags: discussion, answers

Coming from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046878/android-array-of-findviewbyid/24047032?noredirect=1#comment37076860_24047032), people (possibly me) apparently don't understand what a good answer is and when it should happen. It is starting to get out of hand in the comments and I thought maybe a meta discussion would be a good place to point them or to correct me if I'm wrong.

Basically, the OP asked a question and there *still* isn't enough information to answer efficiently. I have commented and voted to close as is appropriate. I have downvoted all of the answers and commented on why (which seems to be a rarity these days). These answers are guesses and this hurts the site, the OP, and others.

Why?

1. The OP may get steered in the wrong direction since he is given information that may or may not help to solve the problem.
2. Other people, seeing 3 similar "answers" may not bother to look at
   it assuming it has been solved. One of these people may have been
   able to help further.
3. The site will continue to get bad posts which may deteriorate the effectiveness of the site if not resolved

With the enormous amount of bad posts we get on SO (Qs and As) and all of the posts on meta addressing that or people asking why their post is so bad or why they get downvotes, I think situations like this are important for the "higher rep" users to understand how we should handle "answers".

These may or may not help the OP but they most likely won't be all that helpful to future visitors which is a big part of our goal (to build an efficient Q&A DB).

**Goal of the post**

I would like someone to point out if they think I handled this inappropriately and if not then maybe us "higher rep" users can be more effective when viewing these posts. There are now at least 7 (The OP, 3 answerers, 2 commenters, and me) users associated with this post so I think everyone could gain from this discussion. Or maybe I'm frustrated with all of the bad posts and need to relax.

Comment: That's not great literature, but is far better than many threads one sees.  You seem to have taken particular offense to it, which is your right, but it doesn't seem to merit calling down lightning to strike it. Downvote and move on.  Let nature take its course.

Comment: We need binding close-votes for gold badge guys! These questions should be closed in a very early stage, before any answers are received. That would simply prevent these problems.

Comment: @HotLicks I am not taking offense to the question or the answers or even the comments telling me I'm wrong. The point is not just about this post but about so many bad posts. There are obviously several users (at least a couple with 2K+ rep) that don't understand how to help keep the site clean. That is what I'm after.

Comment: @kapa I agree but I don't think that will happen very soon. It's probably still too early to ask for more powah this soon after getting the gold dupe hammer

Comment: @codeMagic I love the dupe hammer, but it is barely enough. Those few who are willing to help need more powah, and the quicker the better. It's already too late :).

Comment: @kapa I agree 100% with what you are saying. I'm just not counting on it happening soon enough. As you said, "It's already too late". Anyway, I think you are the only one who understood the point of my post. Maybe I should have had a cold one before posting. Just wanted to get it out there before the comments on the linked post got out of hand.

Comment: @codeMagic These strange users exist, unfortunately not only 2K+ reps, there are even 20K+ reps among them. They don't seem to understand the site and don't care about the rules at all. Even worse, they always give everyone lessons about how the site works :).

Comment: @AD7six I'm sure you are right. And feel free to edit if you have something more clear. I wasn't sure how I wanted to handle it but wanted it out there. And I will see what I can do to make it better and more clear.

Comment: @codeMagic took a crack at it. I feel the pain with this scenario - IME it's common and frustrating to see an off topic question getting guess-answers waiting for it to close OR users inexperienced with a technology/tool that I'm familiar with splashing around and distracting the Asker with something irrelevant whilst they don't update the question with whatever info is missing to allow a useful answer to be given.

Comment: Maybe we need a "NullPointerException" review queue (java) and a "Notice: undefined index" review queue (PHP) ;)

Comment: And an indentation is wrong in Python review queue

Comment: As the question to which you linked has now been removed, mere mortals are unable to see it....was it removed as a result of this discussion?  Is it really helpful to remove questions that are currently being discussed on meta?

Comment: @SList It was closed due to this discussion but then deleted by 3 people. No, it isn't helpful but I could find 10-20 more similar posts fairly quickly (within 2 or 3 pages of questions). I didn't form the post correctly, apparently, because it wasn't necessarily about *that* post. It was more for a consensus on how to handle those types of answers and about higher rep users helping to clean up the site and understanding what is/isn't acceptable answers.

Comment: Why bother? This site never sticks to its rules anyway, so any guidelines will be a matter of interpretation of those who frequent it.

Answer (score 8):

The first action to reach for when encountering a question that is unclear, missing information or otherwise unanswerable is to **close it.**

That said, none of the answers on that question are "Not an Answer."  They are all attempts at answering.  Moderators will not remove answers that are actually answers, no matter how bad the answer is, unless it's clearly not adding any value, or is actively harmful.  Bad answers should be downvoted, not moderator-flagged.

NullPointerException questions are a bit of a special case; *they are all resolved in the same way: find the object you're attempting to dereference which is null.*  There exists [a well-written Canonical/Reference question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) to close such questions as duplicates of; I've closed the question accordingly.

Comment: I agree they are all technically answers and I didn't even consider flagging. My point was simply to have a place to point the users as to how the site actually is suppose to work and not that it is just how **I** think it should work, as some commenters apparently think. Thank you for the link. I will bookmark it and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree about the general point: trying to guess at the answer without additional information is not a good approach, for all the reasons you stated. However, I think you just jumped into a conclusion; this question **was actually answerable**, as posted.

I know this is meta and not SO itself, but let me explain anyway: the key is the `public` keyword in the statement:

```
public TextView[] realtext = { findViewById() ...
```

Just with that snippet, we can tell that this is being assigned in a *member initializer*, which will always produce an NPE.

Luis Lavieri's answer was on target (and for the right reasons); one other was also correct, but does not mention this.

By the way, is this post an answer or should it be a comment? I was not sure... :)

Answer (score 2):

Good answers should be upvoted and bad answers downvoted.

An answer should not be stricken from the archive of Q&A just because it was a lucky guess.

The computer doesn't care if the code it receives is from a guess, vague memories, or years of coding exactly that problem.

Guessing is also a valid technique on some math problems.  Teenagers typically learn to guess answers to quadratic equations from sums and products before they learn the quadratic formula.

Now that all said, what a "guess" answer often lacks is an explanation of how it works, and an answer that includes an explanation is superior.